# Use system channel instead of ringer channel when using EPSSampler in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, audiounit

I'm using [EPSSampler](https://github.com/ElectricPeelSoftware/EPSSampler) to play some notes in my tiny iOS app. It works nicely, except that the sound is controlled through the ringer settings instead of the system volume settings. The problem is that, if the ringer is turned off, my app makes no sound.

The closest I could find was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603970/how-to-play-audio-without-it-referring-to-the-ringers-volume) but I can't quite translate that solution into mine, as I can't match it to EPSSampler's code. Any insight?

**EDIT** To clarify, the only code that deals specifically with audio is contained in the EPSSampler class, my app merely instances it, loads an AUSampler preset, and calls the note-playing methods in EPSSampler, so a solution would need to change something in EPSSampler rather than in my app -- that's why I'm not posting any source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this had nothing to do with EPSSampler, and everything with configuring the audio session. The following code did the trick.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
```

That'll teach me to [RTFM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession).

Answer (score 0):

For swift(Use when initialising the music):

```
_ = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```